# Center list items on one line

Tags: css

I can't work out how to get my list items on one line:

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="navbutton"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="navbutton"><a href="#">Galleries</a></li>
        <li class="navbutton"><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        <li class="navbutton"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar{width:960px; height:46px; list-style-type: none; margin:0 auto; margin-top:1px; text-align:center;}
#navbar li{list-style:none; text-align:center; margin:0 auto; background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px;}
.navbutton{background:url(images/nav/lights_lit.jpg); width:138px; height:45px; display:block; background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.navbutton a{background-image:url(images/nav/lights.jpg); width:138px; height:30px; display:block; text-align:center; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#FFF; text-shadow:#000 0px 1px 4px; font-size:16px; padding-top:15px; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;  background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#navbar a:hover {background-image: url(images/nav/lights.jpg);background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

Live Link:
http://brownbox.net.au/clients/matchlessphotography/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you intended?

[jsFiddle containing your code](http://jsfiddle.net/angstrey/ETAzk/3/)

Here's the code I changed. Float the `li` and get rid of the left/right padding:

```
#navbar li
{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    float: left;
}
```

**UPDATE**

In that case, you have to reduce the width of the #navbar and make sure the left and right margins are set to auto. Here's what I did after reading your comment:

```
#navbar
{
    width: 566px;
    height: 46px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

You will have to play with the width to get it right.

Comment: sure, but if I float it then it won't centre. I need it to center.

Comment: See above. I updated the code after reading your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can float it

```
#navbar {
   height:50px;
   width: 500px; /* just an example */
   margin: 0 auto; /*will center */
}
.navbutton{
   background:url(images/nav/lights_lit.jpg); 
   width:118px; 
   height:35px; 
   display:block; 
   background-position:center; 
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   float:left;
   padding:5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: sure, but if I float it then it won't centre. I need it to center.